# Using while loop in sql

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to loop through my records with a where clause.

I am trying to get only top 100 rows first and then next 100 (some logic i apply with what i get in the select clause)

But, if the first 100 rows does not return a result, it does not goes into 2nd 100 set of data.

My query is :

```
DECLARE @BatchSize INT = 100
DECLARE @Counter INT = 0
DECLARE @TableCount INT = 0
set @TableCount = (select count(*) from Table1)  //@TableCount = 10000

while @Counter < @TableCount/@BatchSize //@Counter < 100
BEGIN        
    SET @Counter=@Counter+1
    INSERT INTO Table4
    SELECT TOP(@BatchSize) * FROM Table2 
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * Table3) and some condition
```

Here, If i dont get the data for first 100 rows, it wont go to next 100 set of data.

What should I do ?

Comment: Loops and SQL are usually an indication you're not thinking in terms of Sets. You really want to think in terms of Sets.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Can you explain me more about this. I didnt understood, I am doing loops because I have millions of rows of data and i dont want to lock the whole table.

Comment: Loops are worse for locking than just running the query.

Comment: @JoeFarrell I am doing this because I want to move the data in other table. I just wrote the select query here as Insert is easy then.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn So, what do you suggest ?

Comment: "`I want to move the data in other table`"  Try a `SELECT INTO` query instead.

Comment: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic642789-338-1.aspx

Comment: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/rbar--row-by-agonizing-row/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `TOP @BatchSize` in the SELECT clause, try `OFFSET @BatchSize * @Counter FETCH NEXT @Batchsize ROWS ONLY` after the WHERE clause.

Based on comments, you may also want to look into a `SELECT INTO` query, as well as the `nolock` query hint.

Comment: I edited the question, Can you let me know how should I use OFFSET here ? Or select into ?

Comment: don't you need ORDER BY for OFFSET?

Comment: @JamieD77 Yes, but you need an ORDER BY to guarantee consistency for his loop, too.

Comment: Ok, I got the anser by offset, so what do you suggest ? I should not go with it ? Or select into ?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn The Select Into will lock the whole database. I dont want that